# jqGrid - The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' '

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and has been struggling to use it within an MVC3 project with no success. I have downloaded the [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/downloads/jqgrid_demo40.zip) and gone through the code but implementing the jqGrid within my project fails with the following error.

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type
'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Index(System.String, System.String,
Int32, Int32)' in 'kags.Web.Controllers.DeptController'. An optional parameter must 
be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

The following is the code in controller:

```
public JsonResult Index(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows){
    var ascending = sord.StartsWith("asc") ? true : false;
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int startRow = (pageIndex *  pageSize) + 1;
    var depts = ListAll()
            .Skip(startRow)
            .Take(pageSize).AsQueryable()
            .OrderByField(sidx, ascending);
    int totalRecords = depts.Count();
    int totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) totalRecords/ (float) pageSize);

    var jsonData = 
              new { total = totalPages,
                    page = page, 
                    records = totalRecords, 
                    rows = (from d in depts
                            select new {
                               i = d.Id,
                               cell = new string[]{d.Name, d.Version.ToString()}
                            })
                            .ToArray()  
                  };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The following is the index.cshtml

```
<h2>Available Depts</h2>
<div>
    <table id="List" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</div>
```

The css and script files for the jqGrid are being loaded from the _Layout.cshtml in shared and are arranged in the correct order.

The following script to support the jqGrid resides in a separate script file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        ("#List").jqGrid({
            url: '/Dept/Index/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Name'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortOrder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Dept List'
        });
    });
```

I have looked at other [samples](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/13/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) but still I am unable to locate why I am getting the error.

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to resolve the error and manage to populate the grid.

Comment: what is kags.Web.Controllers.DeptController? It is obvious that the page parameter is not being filled properly as the framework can't find a way to determine what value to put in it.

Comment: I am certain I had seen an answer from Darin Dimitrov which led me in the right direction but it somehow vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am for sure not any where near Darin Dimitrov's experience and I have no idea how that comment was an answer to what I asked but I will take a stab in the dark any way and say you should make sure the page number you are on is sent to the action method or at least be made optional

```
public JsonResult Index(string sidx, string sord, int page = 1, int rows)
```

Comment: I didn't have any intention of comparing experiences and I am sorry if that is the impression I created. The only thing I was pointing out was I saw an earlier answer but by the time I was trying it out, coming back to comment on it, it was no longer available.  In fact your answer is more preferable as I do not have to add extra code to control for null values.  The code now returns data but the grid does not display and I am trying to find out why.

Comment: I am glad my suggestion helped a bit. I wish I had more experience with javascript to help you out.  I still think you should find a way to get your view to return the page number so the pager function works properly as in this solution it will always display the first page.  Also look at what values are being passed to the controller for the other parameters, maybe that is where the problem is.

Comment: I too get the same error. When I tried doing `int page = 1`, then re-build the solution get the error: **Error 1 Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters**. The solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is one way to look at it..by seeing JtMon answer, It seems pretty good, But i wonder from where you are passing the page and rows value to your controller. This paging you can implement in your view also with JqGrid. but perhaps that is the requirement for you. i would recommend you to remove your page parameter from controller method and do something like this.

```
return Json(new
            {

                page = 1, //first page
                other parameters...
            }
```

and then add following parameter to your grid.

```
jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "totalPages",
        records: "totalRecords",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "id"
        }
```

Let me know if this works out for you or not.